# 1.1 solution on a dedicated machine - how best to move it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, migration, .net-1.1

We have an old project that requires occasional maintenance that uses VS2003 and Dot Net 1.1.  It is on a machine that has become a 'dedicated' machine since no one wants to mess with it. We need to use the machine for other purposes - so I am trying to get it moved to another computer with the least amount of trouble as possible.

I have considered creating a VM for it - since I don't need VS2003 (VS2008 is on all other machines) or the components (we use Devex, Infragistics and a few others that are stuck on old versions on this system).  I should be able to track down the various components to do a reinstall - but don't relish this concept.  Has anyone heard of creating a VM from an existing install of Windows?  Any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for: [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

> Convert Physical Machines to Virtual Machines – Free!

And a slightly [related tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/vmware_converter_windows_linux)..

Comment: Thanks! We have VMWare Workstation so this looks perfect.

Been trying to download it - but the download link for VMware vCenter Converter 4.0 is broken on the VMWare site.   I'll keep looking, and/or contact VMWare..